# Как сделать чтобы табы в TabLayoutPanel были снизу, а не сверху?

Tags: gwt, java

Как сделать чтобы табы в TabLayoutPanel были снизу, а не сверху?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только написать свою компоненту tabbed pane.